# Case Statements/Decode Function in Informatica

Tags: decode, case-statement, informatica-powercenter, informatica

Could anyone help me with writing case statements in Informatica PowerCenter Designer? I am fairly new to Informatica, and based on my limited experience I feel case statements aren't supported. There is a decode function with similar functionality, but I am unable to find any good examples on the syntax.

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me some specific examples on how to use case statements/decode function in Informatica.

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're right - there is no `CASE` statement, but you can use `DECODE` to simulate it:

```
DECODE( TRUE
      , DECIMAL_PORT > 0, 'positive value'
      , DECIMAL_PORT < 0, 'negative value'
                        , 'zero' )
```

It is an equivalent of the following Transact-SQL `CASE` statement:

```
CASE
  WHEN DECIMAL_PORT > 0 THEN 'positive value'
  WHEN DECIMAL_PORT < 0 THEN 'negative value'
  ELSE 'zero'
END
```

Here's how it works:

- the 1st parameter is a hard-coded `TRUE` value,
- even parameters (2nd, 4th and so on) are the **conditions**,
- odd parameters (3rd, 5th and so on) are the **return values**,
- the last parameter is the **default return value**,
- the first condition that evaluates to the value of the 1st parameter (i.e. the first condition that is true) determines the value that is returned,
- if none of the conditions is met the last parameter is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Look also at the IIF() function which is often used to implement conditional logic:

```
IIF(DECIMAL_PORT > 0, 'positive value', IIF(DECIMAL_PORT < 0 ,'negative value', 'zero'))
```

Comment: This will work but it will also get messy quickly as the number of conditions grows. `DECODE` allows to write more readable expressions.