# Decode function in etl informatica

Tags: decode, informatica-powercenter

```
Decode(false,
ivar>10,'variable is greater than 10',
ivar<25, ' variable is less than 25 ',
'No match found ')
```

where ivar=25

What will be the answer as tha options are

..Greater than 10
..Less than 25
..No match found
..Error : expression is invalid

Comment: is this interview question? What do you think the answer should be? Just guess...

Comment: According to me it should be greater than 10 but since both of them satisfies ,have a doubt

Comment: how can it satisfy both ? `25 < 25` is not true.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right answer is: variable is less than 25
because of:

1. [Case Statements/Decode Function in Informatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979163/case-statements-decode-function-in-informatica)
2. [DECODE](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/decode.html)

Try to explain

1. First param is false - that means that we are waiting for the first false
2. first_search than first_result  in params and last - default value that's why i check about the syntax and param numbers and it's ok. Than i'm watch on a value ivar=25
3. 25 < 10 - true, but we need a false. 25 < 25 NO - that's what we are waiting for

If i'm mistaken tell me.